# File creation through fopen works fine on Linux but not on Windows (MS VS 2010)

Tags: c, windows, linux, visual-studio-2010, gcc

Hello there I am trying to execute the .exe file generated by the below code in Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 and I don't see the file being created.

This code when compiled and executed in Linux with GCC works absolutely fine.

To repeat I am able to use the file created in Linux !! but in Windows the .exe program fails to create the file for the name entered by user at command prompt.

Can someone please let me know as to where I am going wrong with respect to the compilers?

Sincere Thanks

```
// filename.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

    #include "stdafx.h"        //Please comment if code is to be executed in GCC
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <memory.h>

    int main()
    {
        FILE *pFile;
        char cNotes_buffer[100];
        memset(cNotes_buffer,0,100);
        printf("Please enter name of the LOG file - with tag MAX 100 characters!! \n");
        if( fgets (cNotes_buffer , 100 , stdin) != NULL )
            {
            fclose (stdin);
        }

        printf("name of file %s \n", cNotes_buffer);
        if ( ( pFile = fopen(cNotes_buffer,"a+") ) == NULL )
        {
            printf("ERROR OPENING FILE FOR LOGGING \n");
            exit(0);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try `perror()` (instead of `printf()`) for the error messages. With `perror()` you also get some more information about the error.

Comment: @pmg AFAIK windows does not have `perror()`. It's `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @RedX: Unless the Windows compiler in use does not conform to ANSI C89 / ISO C90, Windows has `perror()`.

Comment: since he's using visual studio he can use perror(), however might be worth noting that GetLastError can sometimes provide more details

Comment: @pmg Visual Studio compiler is not a C compiler. It's a C++ compiler with C features. But it's good to know it has `perror()`. [MSDN]!(http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yeby3zcb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) indicates that `perror()` is enough though

Comment: There is a potential risk of a buffer overflow in the code posted: `fgets` reads 100 `char`s into a buffer of the same size. It should read one `char` less, to still have one `char` in spare for the terminating 0.

Comment: Why is `stdin` `fclose()`d? At least under linux this makes file discriptor 0 available for re-use which could lead to quite strange behavior if it indeed is reused by a subsequent `open()` or a combination of `fopen()` and `fileno()`.

Comment: @alk: `fgets()` reads 1 less than the specified size (and adds a `'\0'`), so the original statement is pretty safe.

Comment: @pmg: Uh thanks ... - I should have updated my internal man-page cache before commenting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all probability you will press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after entering your file name. So `\n` also gets into `cNotes_buffer`. Now you try to create a file with this buffer as the file name. And I don't think you can create file names with `\n` in it.

Do something like if you've pressed the return key

```
cNotes_buffer[strlen(cNotes_buffer)-1]=0;
```

**EDIT**: Newlines can be present in [filenames](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) in linux but not so on [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) This explains why your file got created in Linux but not on Windows.

Comment: It's possible that his file is being created with the newline char at the end in linux. This is not allowed on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try to `fclose(pFile)`. Failing to close a file causes strange behaviour.

Comment: hello @Pavan Manjunath,@pmg,@CodeChords man thanks for the feedback ..well I missed something really important which was highlighted by Pavan so I was missing that statement where in the \n was been added to filename ...and moreover this works fine in Linux but when the listing of the directory contents is done I get the filename appended with ? atleast on Linux . Thanks